# sagemaker - factorization machines - deserialize model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I estimated a factorization machine model in sagemaker and it saved a file `model.tar.gz` into an s3 folder.

Is there a way I can load this file in Python and access the parameter of the model, i.e. the factors, directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 2019: yes. An official AWS blog post was created to show how to open the SageMaker Factorization Machines artifact and extract its parameters: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/extending-amazon-sagemaker-factorization-machines-algorithm-to-predict-top-x-recommendations/

That being said, be aware that Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithm are primarily built for deployment on AWS, and only [SageMaker XGBoost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html) and [SageMaker BlazingText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html) are designed to produce artifacts interoperable with their open-source equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks! Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by `Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithm are primarily built for deployment on AWS`? In  particular, in what way would it not make sense to directly work with these artifacts?

Comment: in my knowledge only BlazingText and XGBoost are to be read out of AWS. You can always download artifacts for other models and try to make sense of them, but this is not guaranteed to work nor to be stable in the long run. For example, see the in official NTM demo: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/ntm_20newsgroups_topic_modeling/ntm_20newsgroups_topic_model.ipynb "The demonstrated functionalities may not be fully supported or guaranteed. For example, the parameter names may change without notice."